# Update con group by y Having en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema al realizar esta sentencia, ya que no me reconoce el having despues del group by:

```
UPDATE co_account_statement AS ast
INNER JOIN co_fee AS F on f.account_id = ast.account_id
set ast.account_state = "Culminado"
where  f.fee_state = "Completo"
and a.system_state = 1
GROUP by f.account_id
having count(f.account_id) = a.amount_fee
```

Me sale el siguiente error

```
#1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca 'GROUP by f.account_id
having count(f.account_id) = a.amount_fee' en la linea 6
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de solucionarlo, gracias :)

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! escribir en mayusculas se considera grita (y suele verse como mala educacion;) )... ahora.. el campo a.amount_fee, de que tabla viene? porque ninguna tabla tiene como alias a la letra a....

Comment: Además, las dos columnas según el  `group by` no podrían participar del `having` al menos de la forma en que lo están haciendo, por que no explicas un poco más que es lo que buscas hacer con alguna descripción de las tablas?